# model of a quasi static block fading channel in MIMO system

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, noise, algorithms, matrix

can I know what is the model of a quasi static block fading channel in a MIMO system, in function of angle of departure and arrival?

Comment: that depends on the geometry of your mimo array. It's not clear what the fading behaviour has to do with angles.

Comment: if we take a uniform linear array.

Comment: so, you make a drawing and take your knowledge of basic trigonometry to derive the distances between each antenna, from which you directly derive the phase of each channel matrix entry